# How do I make the slides change automatically without having to click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make the slides change automatically?

The code is as follows:

```html
<div id="theme-main-banner" class="banner-one">
  <div data-src="images/home/slide-1.jpg">
    <div class="camera_caption">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="wow fadeInUp animated">Digital Agency <br>And Your Bank <br> Loaner.</h1>
        <p class="wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay="0.2s">We have wide rang of loans section for our customer</p>
        <a href="#" class="button-one wow fadeInLeft animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Apply for Loan</a>
        <a href="service-v1.html" class="button-two wow fadeInRight animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s">See services</a>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.camera_caption -->
  </div>
  <div data-src="images/home/slide-2.jpg">
    <div class="camera_caption">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="wow fadeInUp animated">Digital Agency <br>And Your Bank <br> Loaner.</h1>
        <p class="wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay="0.2s">We have wide rang of loans section for our customer</p>
        <a href="#" class="button-one wow fadeInLeft animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Apply for Loan</a>
        <a href="service-v1.html" class="button-two wow fadeInRight animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s">See services</a>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.camera_caption -->
  </div>
  <div data-src="images/home/slide-3.jpg">
    <div class="camera_caption">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="wow fadeInUp animated">Digital Agency <br>And Your Bank <br> Loaner.</h1>
        <p class="wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay="0.2s">We have wide rang of loans section for our customer</p>
        <a href="#" class="button-one wow fadeInLeft animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Apply for Loan</a>
        <a href="service-v1.html" class="button-two wow fadeInRight animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s">See services</a>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.camera_caption -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /#theme-main-banner -->
```

Comment: Please post your code not the screenshot of it

Comment: I already did thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` to have them show hide at a certain time interval, like this:

```js
var slideEls = [document.querySelector('#slide-1'),
  document.querySelector('#slide-2'),
  document.querySelector('#slide-3')
];
document.querySelector('#slide-2').hidden = true;
document.querySelector('#slide-3').hidden = true;

var i = 0;
var id = window.setInterval(function() {
  if (slideEls[i].hidden) {
    slideEls[i - 1].hidden = true;
    slideEls[i].hidden = false;
  }
  i++;
  if (i >= slideEls.length) {
    window.clearInterval(id);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="theme-main-banner" class="banner-one">
  <div id="slide-1" data-src="images/home/slide-1.jpg">
    <div class="camera_caption">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="wow fadeInUp animated">Digital Agency 1<br>And Your Bank <br> Loaner.</h1>
        <p class="wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay="0.2s">We have wide rang of loans section for our customer</p>
        <a href="#" class="button-one wow fadeInLeft animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Apply for Loan</a>
        <a href="service-v1.html" class="button-two wow fadeInRight animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s">See services</a>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.camera_caption -->
  </div>
  <div id="slide-2" data-src="images/home/slide-2.jpg">
    <div class="camera_caption">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="wow fadeInUp animated">Digital Agency 2<br>And Your Bank <br> Loaner.</h1>
        <p class="wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay="0.2s">We have wide rang of loans section for our customer</p>
        <a href="#" class="button-one wow fadeInLeft animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Apply for Loan</a>
        <a href="service-v1.html" class="button-two wow fadeInRight animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s">See services</a>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.camera_caption -->
  </div>
  <div id="slide-3" data-src="images/home/slide-3.jpg">
    <div class="camera_caption">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="wow fadeInUp animated">Digital Agency 3<br>And Your Bank <br> Loaner.</h1>
        <p class="wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay="0.2s">We have wide rang of loans section for our customer</p>
        <a href="#" class="button-one wow fadeInLeft animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Apply for Loan</a>
        <a href="service-v1.html" class="button-two wow fadeInRight animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s">See services</a>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.camera_caption -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.setInterval` to repeat a function every X milliseconds, and in that function you can programmatically click the `camera_next` div.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('camera_next')[0].click();
}, 10000); // 10 seconds
```

However, this raises a problem. What happens if the interval fires shortly after the user clicks the `camera_prev` or `camera_next` div? The banner would either quickly go back and then forward, or forward twice respectively, and you don't want that. To fix this, you'll need to clear and then recreate the interval whenever the `camera_prev` and `camera_next` divs are clicked.

```
var myInterval;

function createInterval() {
  myInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('camera_next')[0].click();
  }, 10000); // 10 seconds
}
function resetInterval() {
  if (myInterval) window.clearTimeout(myInterval);
  createInterval();
}

createInterval();

document.getElementsByClassName('camera_prev')[0].addEventListener('click', resetInterval);
document.getElementsByClassName('camera_next')[0].addEventListener('click', resetInterval);
```

You likely already have your own click event listeners setup for the `camera_prev` and `camera_next` divs, so you can just call `resetInterval();` inside them.